# Security of JSON in Neo4j array property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have code that successfully does the following:

```
MATCH (c:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = "1234" SET c.Contacts = ['{"Name":"Test","Email":"t1@test.com","Main":"0"}','{"Name":"Test 2","Email":"t2@test.com"}']
```

This works perfectly fine. My concern however is over how can I secure the values of the Array from being hacked/injected?

The typical response would be to use parameters such as:

```
MATCH (c:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = "1234" SET c.Contacts = ['$Element1','$Element2']
```

However this would only replace the values with the JSON I've already received from the user. Is there any way *apart from* sanitising the input myself to secure this through Neo4j? Would sub-parameters be possible::

```
MATCH (c:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = "1234" SET c.Contacts = ['$Element1','$Element2']
'Element1'  => '{"Name":"$Name1","Email":"$Email1","Main":"0/1"}'
```

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track and secure.

Comment: Aren't those just regular strings? (which happen to contain JSON). Using prepared statements/query parameters – as opposed to string interpolation – should be as safe as it gets

Comment: I guess - so that would be safe enough then? Just do something like `[$Element1,$Element2,etc etc]` ?

Comment: FYI: Quoting a parameter (e.g., '$Element1') will cause the string to be used as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect Neo4j to magically protect you somehow if some random string is not legit (whatever that happens to mean, to you).

If you want to limit potential damage, you have to parse the string and verify that it is indeed a JSON object (instead of, say, executable code) with the expected properties and that their values have the right format.

*Aside: If you need to do DB queries on the data in the contacts list, you should not store the contact info in serialized strings.*

##### Sample query

Here is a sample query (where `$cId` and `$contacts` are parameters):

```
MATCH (company:Companies)
WHERE company.CompanyID = $cId
UNWIND $contacts AS contact
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(contact) AS c
WITH c, TOINTEGER(c.Main) AS intMain
WHERE
  c.Name IS NOT NULL AND c.Email IS NOT NULL AND
  c.Email =~ "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"
WITH c, COLLECT(
  apoc.convert.toJson(CASE WHEN intMain IS NULL
    THEN c{.Name, .Email}
    ELSE c{.Name, .Email, .Main} END)) AS cleanContacts
SET c.Contacts = cleanContacts
```

This query only stores contacts:

- That have both the `Name` and `Email` properties.
- Where the `Email` value has the expected format (you can tweak the regular expression).

And, if there is a `Main` property, it is used only if its value can be converted to an integer.

All other properties are dropped.

It stores a new contacts array that contains only validated (stringified JSON) data. The query will fail with an error if `apoc.convert.fromJsonMap` cannot parse any strings in the `$contacts` list.